# Problem 8 (a) in Exercises after Sec. 18 in Munkres' Topology, 2nd ed.: How to show this set is closed?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $X$ be an arbitrary topological space, let $Y$ be an ordered set in the order topology, and let the maps $f, g \colon X \to Y$ be continuous. Then how to show that the set $S$ given by
$$S \colon= \{ \ x \in X \ \colon f(x) \leq g(x) \ \}$$ 
is closed in $X$?

Comment: I'd like the proof to be as elementary and as direct as possible.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott how were you able to spot so quickly that this question of mine is a duplicate? I too would like to be able to do this so as to avoid such duplications in the future.

Comment: @Saaqib: I actually didn’t spot it: someone else, who has now deleted the comment, did, and I checked and saw that he was right. The earlier one was from before I went away for almost a year, and I’d completely forgotten that it existed!